# Trying to Replicate Godaddy MS Shared Hosting Environment on Dev PC

Tags: shared-hosting

I have a unique problem to which I can not find a solution. 
I manage a website which is hosted on IIS 6 from within a Godaddy shared MS hosting package.

Within this hosting package, there are multiple websites being hosted, each with its own domain.

The way Godaddy has set it up is that ONE domain is the "primary" domain. This must be hosted in the root e.g. D:\hosting[USER]. When you browse to domain1.com, it points to the root for this site's files.

All other domains must point to a **subfolder** within that root. e.g. D:\hosting[USER]\site_2\, and when you browse for domain2.com, it points to that subdirectory. When you add a second domain/website, it is done via a godaddy control panel which seems to be unrelated to IIS (e.g. you enter the domain, a subfolder, and click "go", and it's done.)

This is the part I can not replicate on my development PC. on the Dev machine, I can browse the root directory (containing files for site1) by editing my hosts file and pointing domain1.com to my local machine. so far so good.

I tried creating an "application" which points to the 2nd site's subfolder within the root, but I can not make domain2.com point to that subdirectory, etc.

I hope that made sense, and I am hopeful that I just need a nudge in the right direction.

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are several pieces to the puzzle.

I don't have any experience with IIS, so I cannot give you specific tips, but inorder to recreate the dev environment you need 2 things.

1. Your computer needs to recognize that inorder to server domain2.com, it needs to respond itself, and not query the DNS. So you need to "hack" the DNS lookup into returning your own IP i.e 127.0.0.1 (loopback interface). You can find the instructions [here](http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/netsysm/article.php/991281/Net-Tip-etchosts-for-Windows.htm)
2. IIS needs to respond to domain2.com address request, so it needs to know where domain2.com files are. Presumably, you need to configure that somewhere in IIS UI/tools.

Once step 2 is done, wether you host the domain in /hosting/domain1/domain2 or /hosting/domain2, is immaterial from web server's perspective.

Goodluck.

Comment: note I used the linux notation of / to indicate directory structure, for windows, you will use appropriate path indicated by drive letter

Comment: This makes sense - I know about step 1 - and I have that part done, and I think I knew that step 2 needed to be done, I just don't know how :)  Thanks for the point in the right direction